# Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i have a cassandra table and im reading it via spark scala in gcp dataproc.
the below is the optimised code running. but it fails rarely.

```scala
mygcpdf.rdd.repartitionByCassandraReplica(SC.CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE,
      cassandraTable) 
  .joinWithCassandraTable[tbl](SC.CASSANDRA_KEY_SPACE,cassandraTable)
  .on(SomeColumns("col1", "col2", "col3"))

    val newdf = joined.map(x => x._2).toDF(al_cols)
```

throws error: `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)`

is this because the cassandra table doesnt have matching key combiantion for those records it is failing. is there any option to ignore those records and proceed with other.

Comment: What is your target C* cluster version? How does your Spark Cassandra Connector configurations look like? What does your C* query look like? Is your C* cluster properly sized to handle the load? Are you using too many values within `IN` clause? Try setting `spark.cassandra.sql.inClauseToJoinConversionThreshold` to `1` to see if it works properly in that case. Disable `dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable`. There is a lot of unknowns here to properly triage this question so if you could pls update your original question with all the details, it may help readers to suggest you solutions.